# Disallow accessing specific associated object fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

Say I have a model called Home wich belongs_to User.

Given a home object, `@home`, I am currently accessing several user attributes like this:

```
@home.user.name
@home.user.phone
```

Turns out there is some user attributes that I don't want anyone who is consuming a Home instance to access. Is there anyway to acomplish that in Rails?

Example:

If I try to do `@home.user.name` fail, but if I have a user object (`@user`), by itself `@user.name` should not fail.

The reasoning behind this is that there is some attributes on user that should not be there, and I want to gradually remove them from there, and put them into the home instead.  I want to avoid other users of the code to think that they can still access those attributes through `user` and that's why I want to fail.

Comment: I don't think there might be a way to do so. As `@home.user` will return user object itself. Hence we will not be able to distinguish between normal user object and once that we get using `@home.user`. But I would like to know why you want to do so. Can you explain the scenario here. There might be some better solution present for the problem that you are trying to attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Not really possible out of the box with ActiveRecord.

One hacky way to do this would be to override the `#user` method on the Home class, and instead of returning a raw user model, return a proxy object that wraps the user model and only delegates to the attribute accessors you specify.   So something like:

```
class Home < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  def user
    UserProxy.new(user)
  end
end

class UserProxy
  # only methods you specifically delegate will be 
  delegate :screen_name, to: :user
   def initialize(user)
     @user = user
   end

   private
   attr_reader :user
end
```

That being said, I don't recommend it.   Broadly speaking, overriding AR-generated methods will likely cause you long-term pain as requirements evolve and shift.

If restricting attribute access is more of a view-level concern for you, and not a model level concern, then using presenter/view model objects might be a good fit.

Comment: You would have a stack level too deep error there when defining user method no? It will keep calling itself.